# Case statements for multiple fields when only certain cases exist for each field

Tags: mysql, case

We have an inventory feature where we generate Bills. There is an Edit Bill API call. We have implemented it as PATCH call.

A Bill with id = 1 has 2 LineItems :

```
|  Stock Id |   Qty        |  Rate       |
|    10     |      2       |    10       |
|    11     |      3       |    20       |
```

Now lets say I want to change the `quantity for stock Id : 10 to 5` and I want to change the `rate for stock Id : 11 to 40`

We have represented it as PATCH Call :

```
bill : {
    id : 1

    lineItems : [
    {
        stockId : 10,
        qty : 5,
     },

     {
        stockId : 11,
        rate : 40   
     }
    ]
    }
```

In the backend we run following query :

```
 UPDATE `billlineitem` 
SET    `rate` = ( CASE 
                    WHEN stockid = 11 THEN '40' 
                    ELSE rate 
                  END ), 
       `qty` = ( CASE 
                   WHEN stockid = 10 THEN 5 
                   ELSE qty 
                 END ), 
       `updated_billitemquantity_at` = '2019-09-06 05:16:06.219' 
WHERE  `bill_id` = '1' 
       AND `stockid` IN ( 10, 11 )
```

Is it ok, in the above case when there is no change for an attribute then the else clause will take the value from the database for that attribute. The above update statement is run in a transaction.

Is this a correct approach? Will this do an update for every attribute for every stock Id. Is there a better approach?

We are using MySQL DB.

Apart from qty and rate we also have discountType, discountValue and there are other 4 more attributes.

Comment: Seems ok. The other approach is to split into 2 updates. But I don't think there would be much difference.

Comment: my bad. I forgot to mention that there are 6-7 such attributes. I just updated the question.

Comment: Not much different with 7 attributes. The question is how many rows are updated?

Comment: could be between 5-15 rows max. Like a Bill could contain 5 to 15 items/products.

Comment: Assuming there is a (UNIQUE) index on `(bill_id, stockid)`, I don't see a problem then.#

Comment: If an UPDATE updates all rows with the same bill_id, then you could also just use `WHERE  `bill_id` =  1`, without mentioning the stockid in the WHERE.

Comment: I vote for `INDEX(bill_id, stockid)` _and_ keeping the `WHERE` clause.  Uniquness should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single-UPDATE you have seems reasonable.  However, depending on statistics and how well the Optimizer handles `IN`, this 2-UPDATE approach may be faster.

Either will benefit from

```
INDEX(bill_id, stockid)
```

The order of the columns *in the index* matters.  `bill_id` needs to be first for the single-update with the `CASE` statement.  Doing multiple `UPDATEs`, as follows, would not care which order the `INDEX` is written.

```
UPDATE `billlineitem` 
    SET    `rate` =  '40',
           `updated_billitemquantity_at` = '2019-09-06 05:16:06.219' 
    WHERE bill_id = 1
      AND stockid = 11;
UPDATE `billlineitem` 
    SET    `rate` =  '5',
           `updated_billitemquantity_at` = '2019-09-06 05:16:06.219' 
    WHERE bill_id = 1
      AND stockid = 10;
```

(For updating 15 rows, there would need to be 15 `UPDATE` statements; this may be impractical.)

Comment: Thank you Rick. (The order of the columns matters for the 1- update version.) --> Is this for our current approach ? You mean the order of columns to be updated or in the where clause ?

Also, in your solution if there are 15 items to be updated --> we will have 15 UPDATES.  Will that be any problem ?

Comment: @j10 - Sorry, I was a bit vague.  Hopefully, I have clarified that.

Comment: Thank you Rick. That was quite helpful. so the CASE one will be ok for 15 rows? since you mentioned that 15 update Statements may be impratical.

Comment: @Rick_James: slightly confused here: does each CASE Statement condition need to have bill_Id?

Comment: @j10 - Your `UPDATE` with 2 `CASEs` looked fine.  `bill_id` was tested in the `WHERE` where it would be the same for all 15 cases?  Then each `CASE` has the rest of the comparisons.